# ModelSim Timeline Interval Fix

Tags: modelsim

Today I am working with ModelSim for a lab, and I cannot figure out how to change the timeline interval on the bottom of the screen. I want to have every grey vertical line represent 100 ns, but right now it represents 1000 ns. This is too large for me to be able to see my results of the wave. Any help would be great. I have tried right clicking on the timeline and looking through the properties, and I still can't figure it out.

[image: modelsim screen shot]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on EE Stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

You can zoom in/out your waveform using  <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + Mouse scroll or by pressing <kbd>I</kbd> (zoom in) / <kbd>O</kbd> (zoom out).